# Exception in thread "P=69052:O=0:CT" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub

Tags: websphere, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, was

I'm using was 9.0, EJB 3.0 and I written a RMI class to call the remote's EJB. When I run, the console shows me this error:

> Exception in thread "P=69052:O=0:CT" java.lang.ClassCastException:
> org.omg.stub.java.rmi._Remote_Stub

The RMI call:

```
MyEjbRemote ejb = (MyEjbRemote) ctx.lookup(JNDI_NAME_EJB);
```

The remote class has the @Statless and @Remote tags. Does anyone could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSphere uses RMI/IIOP to provide support for EJB remote interfaces, which requires a client side `_Stub` class that implements the EJB remote interface. When the `ctx.lookup()` occurs in a managed thread, the `_Stub` class would normally be generated for you automatically by the container and returned from the lookup, which could then be cast to the remote interface.

Unfortunately, there are a variety of reasons this may not occur.  For example, the lookup is performed from a thin client. For those scenarios, you will need to do one or both of the following:

1 - Perform a `PortableRemoteObject.narrow()` :

```
MyEjbRemote ejb = (MyEjbRemote) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(ctx.lookup(JNDI_NAME_EJB), MyEjbRemote.class);
```

This typically solves issues where the Naming service may have cached a value that has not been narrowed, or perhaps has been narrowed using a different classloader.

2 - Generate the `_Stub` class for the remote interface and package it with the
application code that is performing the lookup. The `createEJBStubs.sh/.bat` command provided by WebSphere may be used to generate the `_Stub` class. Also, if the remote interface extends `java.rmi.Remote`, then you may instead use the RMIC command from the JDK with the `-iiop` option. Information about `createEJBStubs` may be found here:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=beans-create-stubs-command

This solves issues where the thread performing the lookup is not a managed thread. A managed thread is a thread created by the container specifically for running an application. Managed threads contain application context information and have the ability to dynamically generate EJB artifacts, such as `_Stub` classes as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tracy! The both alternatives done well. The first one is more easy, but the second is difficult because the project's dependencies. But I did both and they work well to me.